# How to pass a parameter to an included page with JSF 1.2

Tags: jsp, jsf, jsf-1.2, jspinclude

Is this possible to pass a parameter to an included page in JSF1.2 environment? I have a page a.jsp in which b.jsp is included twice (I tested all jsp:include, a4j:include, c:import) once at top of the page and once at the bottom. I want to figure out in b.jsp if it's now including in top or in bottom of a.jsp.

BTW, I do not have facelets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There the `<jsp:param>` tag is for.

E.g.

```
<jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/include.jsp">
    <jsp:param name="position" value="top" />
</jsp:include>

...

<jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/include.jsp">
    <jsp:param name="position" value="bottom" />
</jsp:include>
```

With the above example, the value is available by `${param.position}` inside the include JSP:

```
<c:if test="${param.position == 'top'}">
    This is a top include.
</c:if>
<c:if test="${param.position == 'bottom'}">
    This is a bottom include.
</c:if>
```