# <jsp:param name="foo"> is not available by #{param.foo} in included JSF page

Tags: jsp, jsf, parameters, el, jsf-1.2

In my application I am using JSF 1.2. I dont want to use facelets taglib so I have included a JSP using jsp:include attribute. I want to pass a variable to subpage which will decide the style class value. Below is the code for parent.jsp

```
<f:view>
...
    <f:subview id="navigation">
        <jsp:include page="/subpage/child.jsp">
            <jsp:param value="page9" name="pageName"/>
        </jsp:include>
    </f:subview> 
...
</f:view>
```

Child jsp is

```
            <f:subview id="navigation">
    ...
                <t:commandLink id="page9" value="mylink" action="#{manageBean.someAction}" 
                  styleClass="#{param.pageName == 'page9'?'stepLinkActive':'stepLink'}" />
    ...
            </f:subview>
```

In above code stepActiveLink class is not getting applied to myLink. Infact #{param.pageName} value is blank.

I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9665520/how-to-pass-a-parameter-to-an-included-page-with-jsf-1-2) on SO which works if I use  surrounding the command link like below

```
        <c:if test='${param.pagename eq "page9"}'>      
            <t:commandLink id="page9"
                value="#{msgs['DICT.ISSUE_CONTROL.SPECIAL_INFO']} "
                action="#{bondIssueBean.gotoModifyPage9}" styleClass="stepLinkActive" />
        </c:if>
        <c:if test='${param.pagename ne "page9"}'>      
            <t:commandLink id="page9"
                value="#{msgs['DICT.ISSUE_CONTROL.SPECIAL_INFO']} "
                action="#{bondIssueBean.gotoModifyPage9}" styleClass="stepLink" />
        </c:if>
```

I have lot of commandLinks which will need to duplicate commandlink definition just to change style class. I wonder, going forward if any other param is passed then it may increase duplicate codes. My questions are

1. Why JSF EL can not identify param value - ${param.paramName}? I also tried accessing param variable using #{param['pageName']} but no luck.
2. How I can replace above if..else so that I can have single commandlink definition?

Comment: Try the JSP EL notation: `styleClass="${param.pageName == 'page9'?'stepLinkActive':'stepLink'}"`.

Comment: @BalusC I was expecting you would atleast comment my question.. :) Thanks. About your suggestion I am getting jsp error 'According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute styleClass does not accept any expressions'

Comment: Okay. Do you really have another `<f:subview id="navigation">` in the `child.jsp`? There should be only one. Remove it.

Comment: Ohh no.. I am just using single child jsp.. I will remove it

Comment: I found an old bug report explaining the cause. I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It fails "by design". For a technical background story see also [JSF issue 629](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-629), which summarizes as follows:

> After some discussion on this issue, we're going to mark this issue as WONTFIX
>   for the follow reasons:
>
> - mainly, this wouldn't have worked in 1.1 if it had not been for the side
>     effect of a fix to get the RI to work in an older version of Tomcat. As
>     soon as that fix was removed, jsp:param would no longer work.
> - the fix for 1.2 is very risky and there probably would have been unintended
>     side effects as a result of adding it.

There's however a possible workaround with help of `<c:set>` which copies it into the request scope so that it's available in JSF EL `#{}` as well.

```
<c:set var="param_pageName" value="${param.pageName}" scope="request" />
<t:commandLink id="page9" value="mylink" action="#{manageBean.someAction}" 
    styleClass="#{param_pageName == 'page9' ? 'stepLinkActive' : 'stepLink'}" />
```

Comment: PeRfEcT!!!:) This explains everything. Workaround solved my problem. Thanks again @BalusC!! I just love to read your answers on SO because of their content..

Answer (score -1):

You can access passed parameter using **#{request.pageName}** EL expression. This is case sensitive and passed parameters are stored in **request** object.

Comment: Problem 1: `<jsp:param>` definitely don't end up in `#{request}`. Problem 2: `#{request}` isn't available in JSP, but only in Facelets. This whole answer is wrong.